# QuestDB: Partition by week

Tags: documentation, questdb

Is there a way to partition tables by week in QuestDB? The QuestDB [documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/concept/partitions/) shows `NONE`, `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, and `HOUR`.

Comment: Hi. Week-based partitioning is not currently supported. I've created a GH issue to track this enhancement: https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/2297. If you feel like contributing, that would be awesome. I left some hints on how to implement this feature.

Comment: There is not a way that you can create Partitions in table based on `week`, But I'm sure it'll be available in future versions so if you want then you can raise a feature request at QuestDB's github repo [HERE](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning by WEEK is supported since version [6.7](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/releases/tag/6.7) .

Example:

```
create table tab ( ts timestamp ) timestamp(ts) partition by WEEK;
insert into tab values ( '2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z' );
insert into tab values ( '2023-01-08T00:00:00.000000Z' );

selecT name, minTimestamp, maxTimestamp from table_partitions('tab');

name    minTimestamp    maxTimestamp
2022-W52    2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
2023-W01    2023-01-08T00:00:00.000000Z 2023-01-08T00:00:00.000000Z
```